# Kendo UI How does the modal popup's schema ID work?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a grid of parent windows and a popup modal B grid of child windows.

The two A and B grids use different database tables, but the configured column names (contents) are the same.

That is, the same table with only a different table name.

I do the dataSource.Insert () of the selected row from the modal popup B grid to the parent A grid and execute the Sync () method.

However, the success of this operation depends on the schema ID of the modal popup B grid.

If the schema ID of the modal popup B grid is an item that exists in the actual field (DB Select XML) of A grid, A grid's Sync () method does not consider it a new item.

Because of this, if you change the schema ID to any value that isn't in the actual field, it will be considered new.

What is the nature of the schema ID?
I want to know exactly what value I need to specify the schema ID.

ex)
Select Query : UserID, UserPW, etc... (select UserID, UserPW from tb_user(A) / tb_user2(B))

"B Grid" Schema ID : "UserID"

result : Rows added with dataSource.Insert () will not be considered new by the Sync() method.

Select Query : UserID, UserPW, etc... (select UserID, UserPW from tb_user(A) / tb_user2(B))

"B Grid" Schema ID : "PleaseSync"  (It didn't really matter what value.)

result : The rows added with dataSource.Insert () are executed by the Sync() method to recognize the new item.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Does grid A have no edit popup but B does? Should insertion in B cause insertion in A? When does saving the new record to the database happen? Type-wise, the id can be any type you want: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model/methods/define It is used to determine if a model instance is new or existing see: [`isNew()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model/methods/isnew)

Comment: First thank you for the answer.
As an easy example, I can show you the current situation.

Create a grid by simply copying it into two grid views (GridView01, GridView02).

Then call GridView02 as a modal popup on GridView01.

Then select the row in GirdView02 and press the Save button. The selected rows will be temporarily added to GirdView01. (datasource.insert ())

Lastly, press Save button in GridView01 and try to save to actual DB with Sync () method.

Comment: However, depending on the schema ID set in GridView02, isNew () is either true or false, as in the question.
Data such as "adsad" is treated as new data. However, data in the actual field is not treated as new data.

Comment: So both grids are sharing a dataSource instance? (I'm assuming you're using MVC, which I don't.) Is that desired behavior, if they're supposed to be saved to two different database tables?

Comment: My sources Grid do not share dataSources instance with each other. Do you need to share it to make it work correctly?

This is the correct behavior that must be stored in different tables.